# New new nav Not finding any questions on tabs with multiple tags

Tags: bug, new-nav

I've got a tab, which effectively points at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone%20windows-phone-8%20windows-phone-8.1%20windows-phone-7.1%20uwp%20win-universal-app%20entity-framework-core?mode=any

I see live updates when looking at my other tabs to tell me I've got new questions over there, but every time I click through, I get the:

[image: That's a miss, Sorry, that filter combination has no results. Please try different criteria.]

Even though clicking loading the search for any of the individual tags brings results back.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) (possibly because it's a synonym of [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app)).  If you try this URL, it works as desired.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone%20windows-phone-8%20windows-phone-8.1%20windows-phone-7.1%20win-universal-app%20entity-framework-core?mode=any

Comment: could it be that synonym was made after my tab (which *used to* work), in which case the bug is that creation of synonyms breaks tabs?

Comment: Yes, that certainly sounds like a side-effect, as the synonym was recently approved 4 days ago.

Comment: Well, manually faffing with the URL, and recreating the tab from scratch appears to work (as you cannot use the cursor to scroll through the tags to remove the offending one), so definitely looks like a bug as a result of a synonym being approved...

Answer (score 0):

Tags use *and* logic by default.  So you need to use the search box and separate the tags with *or*, for example with the search [`[windows-phone-8] or [windows-phone-8.1] or [windows-phone-7.1] or [win-universal-app] or [entity-framework-core] or [windows-phone]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8%20or%20windows-phone-8.1%20or%20windows-phone-7.1%20or%20win-universal-app%20or%20entity-framework-core%20or%20windows-phone).  Currently with this many tags, the new-nav does not display the tag selection gracefully, but it does return over 33k results.

> [image]

For more reading, look into the [help for search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: If you look at the end of the URL, it does specify `any`, but the URL loads as if the mode is `all`.  There's some other issue at work.